# node-auth0 new ManagementClient instant in nextjs serverless architecture

Tags: node.js, next.js, serverless, auth0

I'm using the ManagementClient from `node-auth0` to update user in a nextjs's route handlers:

```
// file auth0-manager
import { ManagementClient } from 'node-auth0';

export const management = new ManagementClient({
  domain: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_DOMAIN || '',
  clientId: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID,
  clientSecret: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET,
  scope: 'delete:users update:users',
});
```

```
import { management } from '../auth0-manager';

export const GET = async function myApiRoute() { 
  await management.users.update(...);
  return Response.json({...});
};
```

The above code works locally. But will there be a problem if it's deployed to Vercel's serverless architecture, since `management` is an instance that can be shared by different api routes?

Should I update my code like this:

```
import { ManagementClient } from 'node-auth0';

export const management = () => new ManagementClient({
  domain: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_DOMAIN || '',
  clientId: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID,
  clientSecret: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET,
  scope: 'delete:users update:users',
});
```

```
import { management } from '../auth0-manager';

export const GET = async function myApiRoute() { 
  await management().users.update(...);
  return Response.json({...});
};
```

I will be grateful if anyone could help.